# Turning table with lat and long columns into point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-processing, latitude-longitude, point-creation

I have a table as a layer in QGIS. It includes two columns: `"Lat"` and `"Long"`.

I would like to use these as geometry columns.

How would I do this without saving and reloading a table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the "[Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression)" tool to create a temporary point layer from your table using the expression:

```
make_point("lon_or_X_field", "lat_or_Y_field")
```

[image]